# Android data statistics

Tags: java, android, traffic-measurement

I am aware of http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html what the API doesn't say is for what time frame the bytes are counted? Is it per day, per month or for the complete lifetime of the mobile?

What would be the way to determine the mobile data traffic for a given time frame? e.g. per Month or from 2nd of Feb to 6th of Feb?

Is it possible as well to get the duration of the data link? For example I don't care about the amount of data just about the online time via mobile network?

Thanks, A.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at implementing analytics into the app? Google Analytics is free, and they provide an SDK for Android. More info [here](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/android/). I believe Flurry is also free, and gets pretty good reviews. If you have websites related to the app (or they are part of a single "brand"), I'd implement GA on both so you can easily compare performance/visitor behavior on all of your platforms in one place.